# Testing on Android Hardware without a SIM Card

Tags: android

I'm trying to test an application on an actual Android device (the main reason is to test the Bluetooth functionality, which the emulator cannot help with :( ). To help with my endeavor, I'm thinking about buying an Unlocked HTC G1 from eBay. My question is will I be able to use the unlocked phone without any SIM card at all? Ideally, I'd like to be able to use wi-fi and other native apps, but my main focus would be to test my application, without having a SIM card.

If there are any better phones, or alternative strategies that I should employ, I'd be grateful to hear about them.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I develop Android games and have Google's ADP 1 (G1) and Nexus One, both SIM unlocked and regularly used without SIM, not problems at all. Also the former is rooted, while the N1 is not.

Answer (score 0):

I have a G2 without a SIM card that I use for testing, works perfectly, the difference is you wont see some apps in the market. You can either buy an unlocked phone or get a lock one and unlock it for under 10$ on ebay.

Comment: Are you sure market apps can filter out phones without a SIM card currently installed? Sounds weird. AFAIK an app can require telephony services, which would discard some tablets, but never phones, regardless of whether there's a SIM installed on them or not.

Comment: Yes, im sure, some apps will only appear in certaint countries. "Not all users can see paid apps. To show paid apps, a device must have a SIM card and be running Android 1.1 or later, and it must be in a country (as determined by SIM carrier) in which paid apps are available." Taken from http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html

Answer (score 0):

you won't have any problems no android phone that I know of requires service to use.  I test with my G1 all the time with no sim in it.